# Must a locally compact, second countable, Hausdorff space support a Radon measure?

Tags: gn.general-topology, measure-theory

Let $X$ be a locally compact, second countable and Hausdorff space, must there be a Radon measure on $X$ whose support is $X$?

The motivation for this question comes from Anton Deitmar's paper [On Haar systems for groupoids](https://arxiv.org/abs/1605.08580), in which he construct a groupoid with open range map admitting no Haar system starting from a locally compact (actually compact) Hausdorff space that supports no Radon measures. Deitmar then conjectures that all locally compact, second countable and Hausdorff groupoids with an open range map have a Haar system, so I believe that either there are no known counterexamples or that the answer to my question is positive, but I haven't been able to find neither a counterexample nor a proof.

Comment: What about Dirac measures?

Comment: Oh I see, you are asking for the support of the measure to be $X$

Comment: Yes, sorry, I meant to write "must there be a Radon measure supported on $X$" but I skipped a (crucial) word. Thanks to YCor for editing it!

Comment: $\sum \lambda_n \delta_{t_n}$ for a positive $\ell^1$ sequence of scalars and a dense sequence?

Comment: I think your comment should be an answer @user131781

Comment: Incidentally, a locally compact, second countable Hausdorff space is Polish.

Comment: How do you show metrizability without assuming regularity? I was thinking of Urysohn's metrization theorem @Nate

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti: Locally compact Hausdorff spaces are regular (elementary exercise or see https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1313688/show-that-a-locally-compact-hausdorff-space-is-regular).  Indeed they are completely regular - that's a version of Urysohn's lemma.

Comment: @AlessandroCodenotti: Alternatively, consider the one-point compactification $X'$, which is compact Hausdorff and also second countable.  Compact Hausdorff spaces are regular (an even easier exercise) and so $X'$ is metrizable; since it's compact any compatible metric is complete.  Now $X = X' \setminus \{\infty\}$ is an open subset of a complete metric space, hence it too is completely metrizable (with a different metric).

Comment: Of course, I had forgotten that compact Hausdorff spaces are regular (and normal), thanks!

Comment: Also, if $X$ has no isolated points, you can even find a full-support measure which is atomless.  Let $U_n$ be a countable base.  Since $X$ is Polish, each $U_n$ contains a copy of Cantor space $2^\omega$, on which you can put Cantor (aka Lebesgue) measure, $\mu_n$.  Now consider $\mu = \sum 2^{-n} \mu_n$.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

At the OP‘s request——consider $\sum \lambda_n \delta_{t_n}$ where $(\lambda_n)$ is a sequence of positive scalars which sum to $1$ and $(t_n)$ is a dense sequence.